# React Router Confirm Navigation to a page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working to learn React. The sample project was designed to be used with React 0.13.3 and react-router 0.13.3. I am using react 15.4.1 and react-router 3.0.0

The sample project uses willTransitionTo to do a simple confirmation before allowing the user to navigate to a page. here is the code:

```
var About = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    willTransitionTo: function(transition, params, query, callback) {
      if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to read a page that\'s this boring?')) {
        transition.about();
      } else {
        callback();
      }
}, ...
```

I know in the version of react-router I am using, the above no longer works. So following the auth-flow example found [on the react router docs page](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js) I converted my code to use the onEnter convention. here is what I have thus far:

```
function confirmTransition(nextState, replace){
    if(comfirm('Are you sure you want to read a page that\'s this boring?')){
        replace({
            pathname: '/about',
            state: {nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname}
        });
    }
}

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={require('./components/app')}>
            <IndexRoute component={require('./components/homePage')} />
            <Route path="/authors" component={require('./components/authors/authorPage')} />
            <Route path="/about" component={require('./components/about/aboutPage')} />
            <Redirect from="about-us" to="about" />
            <Route path='*' component={require('./components/notFoundPage')} onEnter={confirmTransition}/>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'));
```

The issue I'm having is when I try to navigate to the about page, the onEnter does not fire.

I'm certain I am missing something. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I'm... well not intelligent. I found I had placed the onEnter on the wrong route.

Thank you all for not pointing that out.